# Is there a way to use custom attributes for Amazon Cognito using the Hosted UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, field, registration

I'm trying to use the Hosted UI feature with AWS Cognito's User Pool to create a login / signup form for a web application.

I can select certain "standard attributes" for user registration,  and those show up on the Hosted UI.  For example these attributes...
[image]

Show up like this on the Hosted UI...

[image]

But if I were to add some custom attributes...

[image]

Nothing changes, and the Signup fields and form look exactly like they do in the middle picture.  They are basically hidden attributes to that UI.

Is there any way to make those custom fields populate so that a user can fill them in?

Furthermore... These custom attributes don't even show up in the user's information from my User Pool 'Users and groups' area.  As you can see, the only attributes showing up are those 'standard attributes'.  The custom ones are nowhere to be found.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

AWS says that at this moment, unfortunately, it is not possible to show the custom attributes on the Cognito hosted UI sign-up page. Also, the custom attributes cannot be marked as “required”.

As for the second Question.  Custom attributes will not be reflected in the Users/Groups area until they are added to the user, which, again, cannot be done through the Hosted UI.